# Does the 2nd welfare theorem involve government intervention?

Tags: public-economics, welfare-economics

How is the initial redistribution of resources carried out?

Answer (score 4):

The second welfare theorem does not necessarily involve a government as such. It does not matter for the theorem who redistributes the resources. Nevertheless, in practice this will most likely often involve the government.